# I am trying to save the profile_picture which came from SignupForm in my user model named UserProfile

Tags: django

i am trying to save the profile picture which has came from SignupForm but intead saving that file, i dont know django is always taking the default.jpg
i tried but i am not able to do

could you help me to get this resolve

however
i am trying to save all the credentials of user to the respected `UserProfile` once they signup,
my all the credentials are saving correctly,
but i dont know why only the profile_picture is not able to taken from `SignupForms` instead it is using default.jpg which defined in my models.py

forms.py of my app

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import UserProfile
    
    class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
        first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
        last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
        profile_picture = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': False}))
        email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, required=True)
        address_line1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
        city = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
        state = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
        pincode = forms.CharField(max_length=6, required=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'profile_picture', 'address_line1', 'city', 'state', 'pincode')
        
        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super().save(commit=commit)
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=user)
            user_profile.address_line1 = self.cleaned_data['address_line1']
            user_profile.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
            user_profile.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
            user_profile.pincode = self.cleaned_data['pincode']
            if self.cleaned_data['profile_picture']:
                # Save the uploaded image file with the user's username as the filename
                image_file = self.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
                file_extension = image_file.name.split('.')[-1]
                file_name = f'{user.username}.{file_extension}'
                user_profile.profile_picture.save(file_name, ContentFile(image_file.read()), save=False)
            user_profile.save()
            return user
```

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)
        profile_picture = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

here is my `view.py`

```
def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignupForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                profile.address_line1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line1']
                profile.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
                profile.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
                profile.pincode = form.cleaned_data['pincode']
                if form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']:
                    profile.profile_picture = form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
                if request.POST.get('user_type') == 'patient':
                    profile.is_patient = True
                else:
                    profile.is_doctor = True
                profile.save()
                messages.success(request, 'User created successfully!')
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = SignupForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.dj', {'form': form})
```

Comment: did you check if there is a picture uploaded so `if form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']` is TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on your form you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, your picture will not work.

Example:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
</form>
```